# nodejs callback closure when accesing an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, closures

this is my problem.

i have a piece of code and when i run that code thats in the callback it can't find the var out side the callback and original function.

```
var counts = [];

collection.count({vote:'walibi'}, function(err, votecount) {
   counts.push(votecount);
});
```

so when i run the code "counts.push" it dont trow an error at me,
but it just dont do enything at all.

i already trieded to put the var in to the callback but then i cant acces it from outside.

i hope some of you can help me with this.

Comment: The code snippet you've posted works as-is. I'm guessing the actual code you have has the `counts` somewhere outside of the parent/inherited scope. Unless of course you meant that `counts` is still empty immdediately after you call `collection.count()`. If that is the case, then that's a different issue and is because `collection.count()` is asynchronous.

Comment: Please post an example the demonstrates your problem exactly. In particular, it's important to see where you're testing for evidence that `counts.push` does nothing (e.g., where is your `console.log`?).